# How to configure VS Code Auto import?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

Is there a way of tweaking TypeScript Auto import feature in Visual Studio Code?

As an example, observe the following attempt:

[image]

The added line by the Auto import was the following:

```
import { Pins } from '../types/index';
```

I would like it to be added straight away without the comma, in respect to TSLint, and without the `/index` path, due to my subject sense of aesthetics, like the following:

```
import { Pins } from '../types'
```

Is there a way of saving those few "extra" keyboard hits?

Comment: You could install the TypeScript-Hero extension for VSCode and configure it to remove the semicolon on save. It has many possible configurations for setting up clean import statements. Though I can't find the documentation anymore since it migrated to GitLab.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [TypeScript Hero](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbbit.typescript-hero) extension.
2. Go to settings (`Ctrl` + `,`).
3. In settings go to `User` (selected default) >> `Extensions` >> `TypeScript Hero`

TypeScript Hero > **Imports: Insert Semicolons**

[x] Defines if there should be a semicolon at the end of the statement.